# Joining two strings using rlike

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am joining the tables `Table_A` and `Table_B` on columns `Col_A` and `Col_B`. Below are some test sample values.

```
Table_A, Col_A
USA1FullCover
USAMainland
USA2Islands

Table_B, Col_B
USA
USA1
USA2
```

When joining, I need to match the value '`USA`' followed by a number exactly. For instance, the join result should look like this.

```
Col_A          Col_B
USA1FullCover  USA1
USAMainland    USA
USA2Island     USA2
```

I'm trying to achieve this in MySQL. I tried the `rlike` function. But the issue is that with `rlike`, I am not able to completely match them.

```
select
case when 'USA1FullCover' rlike 'USA' then 1 else 0 end;
#matches, but shouldn't

select
case when 'USA1FullCover' rlike 'USA1' then 1 else 0 end;
#matches, which is what I need/expect

select
case when 'USA1FullCover' rlike 'USA2' then 1 else 0 end;
#doesn't match, which is what I need/expect
```

My question is how can I fix the `rlike` so that the first case doesn't happen i.e. it doesn't match when there is no digit on the RHS? Or is it possible using `regex`? Taking a substring of the LHS doesn't help since we cannot really define the length beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
col_A regexp '^USA[0-9]{1}.+$'
```

to match USA followed by exactly one digit followed by any other characters.

To join only when such pattern exists

```
select a.*,b.*
from tableA a
join tableB b on 
case when a.col_A regexp '^USA[0-9]{1}.+$' then substring(a.col_A,1,4) else '' end
= b.col_B
```

Comment: Thank you! I just tried this, but won't this work only if there is a digit after USA? I also have cases where we don't have any digits and need to match those too...

Comment: that is what your question said. you can change the else part to handle those which don't have a digit after USA